# Prevent initWithContentsOfURL: from using cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, url, caching

I'm using this line to get the contents of a URL:

```
NSString *result=[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                   error:nil];
```

The problem is when there's a bad connection, it loads the contents from cache. Is there a way to avoid this behaviour? For example, clearing the cache or something.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `initWithContentsOfURL:` for network operations anyways. Use an `NSURLRequest`.

Comment: If you use NSURLRequest, you can then turn caching off so nothing will ever be cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's not recommended to use `initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error` to load data from a network resource.

Second, if you want to control caching behavior, you should be using an `NSURLRequest`. `NSURLRequest` allows you to customize the caching behavior of the request by setting the `cachePolicy` of the request. In your case, you want to use `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`. An example of doing this synchronously using `NSURLConnection` would be:

```
NSString        *result     = nil;
NSData          *data       = nil;
NSURLResponse   *response   = nil;
NSURLError      *error      = nil;
NSURLRequest    *request    = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:20L];
data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (response != nil && [data length] > 0){
    result = [NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Note that this is a very naive implementation that does not check the HTTP status code returned, the mime-type of the response, or perform any error handling. It is also not a recommended practice to load network resources synchronously or to do so from the main thread. A better implementation would use `sendAsynchronousRequest:completion:` or `NSURLSession`.

However, it does demonstrate at a high level what you would need to do to answer your question: The NSURLRequest specifies that this request should never use the local cache, and the returned data is used to create an instance of `NSString`.

Comment: okay i used it and it worked fine, but when there's a bad connection it still loads previous results. Do you think the server is responding from its cache (if it exists). I'm using a simple php script which echoes the content of an xml file.

Comment: It's possible, especially if your script is hosted behind a caching load balancer or CDN. The best way to troubleshoot this is to use a debugging proxy like Charles and run that while your application runs. You will be able to see exactly what is coming from the server.

Comment: i solved it by adding this header to my script : header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); thank you very much for your help anyway.

Comment: If you have control of the server, that's definitely the correct way to get the behavior you seem to want. The must-revalidate should not be necessary. You can check your script using http://red-bot.org

Answer (score 0):

Simple cache-buster dummy parameter with random value added to URL should work. 
And as @Josh-Caswell said, use `NSURLRequest`.  Although in case of proxy servers, just using `NSURLRequest` may not help and you will still need cache-buster.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to load a string from nsurlrequest please ?

Comment: Almost complete source here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-SW1